# unable to save data to localStorage using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

Hi friends I'm new into angular and wanted to create a single page application.

My code working fine when create a list of products and when click on product I will land to detail page which is working absolutely fine but But now I want to show a another list which will show already viewed products.

I stared to dig out the solutions and came up with some idea to push `ProductId` in some array by using `$routePrams` which is working fine until user reload the page because after reload the page all the saved `ProductId` vanished from array. I also tried to save data to localstorage but failed and then came here for seeking help... Please check my code below and please suggest if their is any other way to crack this shit

**controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('assignment', ['ngRoute']);



var viewedProducts = []; // created a global empty array
var uniqueNames = [];  // created second global empty array


myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/',{
      templateUrl : 'list/list.html'
    })
  .when('/:productId',{ // Passing productId 
    templateUrl : 'detail/detail.html'
  })

}])

myApp.service('myData', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    itemList : function(){
      return $http({'method': 'GET', 'url' : 'js/data.json'}).then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      }, function(data){
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
  }
}])

myApp.controller('itemData', ['$scope','$http', 'myData', function($scope, $http, myData){

  myData.itemList().then(function(data){
    $scope.items = data;

  }, function(){
    console.log(data);
  })



}])

myApp.controller('details', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'myData', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, myData){
  $scope.product = $routeParams; // Getting Product Id using $routeParams


  myData.itemList().then(function(data){


    angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){ 

      if(value.productId == $routeParams.productId) {
        $scope.product = value; 


        viewedProducts.push(value.productId);

        /*Trying to same data to localStorage*/
        localStorage.setItem('viewedItems', viewedProducts);
        var getViewed = localStorage.getItem('viewedItems');
        getViewed = getViewed.split(',')

        angular.forEach(getViewed, function(value, key){
            if(uniqueNames.indexOf(viewedProducts[key]) === -1) {
              uniqueNames.push(viewedProducts[key]);
            }
        });
      }

    });

  });

}])

myApp.controller('viewedProducts', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams' , 'myData', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, myData){

$scope.viewed = [];

  myData.itemList().then(function(data){
    //$scope.items = data
    angular.forEach(data, function(datavalue, datakey){

      angular.forEach(uniqueNames, function(value, key){
        if (datavalue.productId == uniqueNames[key] && datavalue.productId !== $routeParams.productId) {
          $scope.viewed.push(datavalue);
        }
      });

    });
  })

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

$window.localStorage.setItem(key,value)

localStorage only supports strings, so you need to stringify your array with JSON.stringify().

Here is an [in-depth solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage/23516713#23516713)

or you can use an angular module for this like [angular-localstorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Answer (score 0):

Its because localstorage only support string as Values.

Hence for storing the data use

```
localStorage.setItem('viewedItems', JSON.stringify(viewedProducts));
```

And for retriving the data use

```
var getViewed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('viewedItems'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced a similar issue like this and i used `ngStorage` which will provide both `$localStorage and $sessionStorage` services.

You can define it like this

```
controller('savedata', function($scope, $localStorage) {
  $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
    x: 42
   });
});
```

Here is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tD7Jms1p7YmnDLUBAwe?p=preview)

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have updated your myData service to make use of storage,
please check if this works,

```
myApp.service('myData', ['$http', '$window', '$q', '$timeout', function($http, $window, $q, $timeout) {
    var storage = $window.localStorage;

    return {
        itemList: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                list = storage.getItem('item-list');

            if (list) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    deferred.resolve(angular.toJson(list));
                });
            } else {

                $http({ 'method': 'GET', 'url': 'js/data.json' })
                    .then(function(response) {
                            storage.setItem('item-list', angular.fromJson(response.data));
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        },
                        function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            deferred.reject(data);
                        });
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```